Parallel.For slower than regular For when writing to BitArray
Could anyone explain why does Parallel.For behave slower than For when writing to BitArray? Does it have anything to do with memory locks?
float[] output = new float[100000];
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(output.Length);
Parallel.For(0, output.Length, i =>
{
  bitArray[i] = output[i] > 0.5f;
});

float[] output = new float[100000];
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(output.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
{
  bitArray[i] = output[i] > 0.5f;
}

Expected Parallel.For to be faster than For, but on my machine it took two orders of magnitude more time than the other (+10s vs 100ms).

Writing to a BitArray isn't locked and it's not thread-safe, which also means that you shouldn't be doing this

I've never done anything with SIMD myself, but if performance is a factor, then SIMD might be what you're looking for?

If you do use SIMD, Vector256.ExtractMostSignificantBits is nice to convert the result of the comparison to packed bits, skipping the ugly one-by-one testing booleans and conditionally setting/resetting individual bits (read-modify-write) of an int[] (which is what happens inside BitArray).

A parallel execution has some overhead by its nature and if that overhead has nearly the same workload as the work itself (as in this example) it is not worth to do it in parallel

The problem is probably false sharing. See this answer.

@SirRufo Sure, but 10s for spawning some threads? Spawning some threads should take microseconds.

@asdfldsfdfjjfddjf FYI I tested the above code with BenchmarkDotNet and got 1,535.3 us with Parallel.For vs. 349.9 us with simple for.

Parallel.For creates a delegate each iteration When to use Parallel.For? and that is much more expensive than the few instructions necessary to toggle a bit.
Even the for loop is wildly inefficient as the compiler generates a function call for each bitset: godbolt.
The following naive C implementation runs in 0.6 milliseconds. For true speed you should use SIMD instructions as mentioned in the comments.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

size_t ceildiv(size_t a, size_t b)
{
    return (a + b - 1) / b;
}

double wtime(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (double)(tv.tv_usec / 1e6 + tv.tv_sec);
}

int main()
{
    double start = wtime();
    size_t n = 100000;
    float *output = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    uint64_t *bitmap = calloc(ceildiv(n, 64), 64);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bitmap[i / 64] |= (output[i] > 0.5) << (i % 64);
    }

    free(bitmap);
    free(output);
    double end = wtime();

    printf("Time: %lfms\n", (end - start) * 1e3);
}


This is a C# question, not C.

There are several reasons why your parallel code is slower.  Let's keep in mind the main reason to use parallel threads: You have tasks that are CPU-bound and wish to divide the workload.
The problem is that your code is NOT CPU-bound in the first place.  A simple loop over 100_000 iterations is not hogging the CPU.  About 8 years ago, using a 3.0 GHz CPU, I found that I could go through 600_000 iterations before parallel threads would be beneficial.
Next, BitArray is a horrible example for using Parallel.For iterating 1 index at a time?  As mentioned in a comment, it is not thread-safe but what I want to point out is that a BitArray is backed by a list of integers.  So an individual bit in the BitArray maps to a bit on an integer.  And with Parallel.For, your loop may be attempting to set individual bits belonging to the same backing integer, which causes many performance issues.  Yikes!
A better example would be try using a bool[].  There would be less performance conflicts.  Even still, do not expect this to perform better than a simple serial loop.
What could be done to create a loop that rivals or surpasses a serial performance?  Besides using a bool[], you should try to increase the array length to half a million or more.  But you will still find Parallel.For is slower.
Why?  Because Parallel.For creates a new task for each index.  Granted, creating a task is a relatively low-impact call but when you create 100K up to 1 million, then a lot of those little impact things add up to a big impact.  You could still use parallel threads but the focus should be to create just a few, and not 100K.
You can investiage using a Range Partitioner.  Or you can simple create your own chunks based on the array length.  A general rule of thumb I apply is to use twice the number of CPU's.  That is 2 * Environment.ProcessorCount.  Divide the array length by that value to produce a range size.  If it does not divide evenly, i.e. has a remainder, then add 1 to the range size.  Now just create your own ranges based on that range size.
You can then process each range in parallel.  Instead of creating 100K threads, you have created a much smaller amount so you have minimized the overhead of creating tasks.
If you still insist on using BitArray, then the challenge is to produce a range size that is also evenly divided by 32.  Why?  Because that why a backing intger will belong to only one range.  While you process the many ranges in parallel, you still process a given range serially.  Since the backing integer would belong to only 1 range, you do not encounter performance conflicts.
Below is a link to a Paritioner class:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner?view=net-8.0

"Because Parallel.For creates a new task for each index." -- Citation?

"Your loop may be attempting to set individual bits belonging to the same backing integer, which causes many performance issues. Yikes!" -- I would be more concerned about the correctness issues. I program that produces incorrect results is useless, actually harmful, whether runs fast or slow.

@TheodorZoulias Maybe I read the OP wrong.  I read the word "slower" in the first sentence, "faster" in the last sentence, and saw the tag "performance", and for some strange reason I thought the OP wanted someone to explain why it performed so poorly.  My bad.  Sorry I took time out of my work day to try to explain performance issues to someone who asked for an explanation about performance issues.

Rick there is no reason to apologize. You did what you thought was right, and I did what I thought was right, which is downvote an answer that contains erroneous information about the Parallel.For creating a new task for each index. I didn't downvote it for focusing on what the OP asked, and ignoring the elephant in the room, which is that the program produces garbage results. If you ignore the elephant, someone else has the duty to mention the elephant. That's how it goes.

@TheodorZoulias If the OP follows my suggestions, garbage results will not occur.  If he replaces the BitArray with a bool[] OR uses a BitArray with partitioned ranges using a range size evenly divisible by 32, the results will be correct.

Rick the BitArray is not thread-safe, period. If you use a non-thread-safe component in a multithreaded environment without synchronization, your program has undefined behavior. Microsoft will dismiss any bug report about any behavior that is not desirable, as incorrect use of their products. Suggesting to do tricks with partitioners in order to keep using a non-thread-safe component in a multithreaded environment without synchronization, is a downvoteable offense by itself.
